# Notching Rafters for wires to res

Tags: framing

Is it safe from a structural standpoint to put small notches ( 1 inch deep x 3 1/2 in long at the deepest/longest point, not the whole area) in 5ea of the 2x6 bottom chords across attic area that run from front of house to back of house to allow wires running though the area to lay so i can put plywood pieces down and use area as storage and not have the plywood sitting on wires?

Comment: Probably not **rafters**, given the apparent location. **Lower truss members** or **ceiling joists** more likely. A picture would be helpful. Many attics not built as storage in the first place have very little margin for reducing structure which my be inadequate as built for storage.

Comment: They are 2 x 6 ceiling joists or lower trusts that run across walls from front to back of house. Its actual only about 1/2 in botch. Can that really affect the strengh?

Comment: Yes it can. If the span of the joists are already marginal for strength which is common in older homes, any notch can be bad, depending on where it is. Help us understand more by stating the overall length of the joists (give or take 6") and if there is a center support or not. A picture in addition to that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. You'll weaken the rafters.   Edge cuts are particularly harmful to structural members.

If anything, you would rip a whole bunch of shims, (say, 7/8" thick), and lay them across the tops of the rafters, omitting them where the wires are.   Or sister the rafters.

- However, this would create a second code violation: wires too close to the floor surface, and vulnerable to being nicked by nails.   This can be remedied by putting steel "nail plates" above the wires to guard them from nails up to 1-3/4" long.  However it wouldn't be enough to protect only above the rafters, because the cables are being drawn taut *between* rafters, so they are vulnerable there too, especially near the rafters.

  - Stapling the wires to the rafters and using sufficiently thick shims would take care of that.

You're also not allowed to cut the -- well, hold on. You're not allowed to cut the cables and then make a desperate, taut splice with what little length remains.   You are allowed to cut, reroute and splice additional length in the middle.  However all splicing must be inside junction boxes*, and the boxes must remain accessible forever.   I recommend large-ish steel boxes, because if you do have a bad connection that arcs, the steel won't melt and burn through, and will distribute the heat around the entire box, reducing the chance of any point turning hot enough to ignite building materials.

Steel junction boxes, plus non-flexible metal conduit (EMT, RMC or IMC) are a great way to make the "shim" strategy actually work.  Now the shim needs to be no thicker than the pipes, i.e. 7/8".  These tough pipes *are their own nail plates*, taking that problem off the table. Inside the conduit, you'd use THHN/THWN-2 individual wires; up to 4 circuits per conduit pipe. The pipes are also their own grounds, meaning no need to push ground wires through the conduits.  Most circuits only need 2 wires, and the 1/2" trade size of these pipes can support 9 or 10.

- There's no profit in using 3/4" pipe.  You could use 1" pipe and put up to 10 circuits in a pipe, but the wires in the pipe would need a wire size "bump", 14 AWG cable -> 12 AWG THHN, 12 AWG cable -> 10 AWG THHN. In those cases I prefer to lay two or three 1/2" pipes, especially if bending is involved.

---

* If you ask how to splice without a junction box, the Home Depot clerk will cheerfully press [one of these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-Romex-Splice-Kit-2-Wire-1-Clam-A22899-000/202204326) into your hands.  No mention will be made of the fact that these are illegal, except in very particular applications.  These are the same dim-bulbs who will cheerfully recommend a NEMA 10 dryer outlet "since it's universal".

Comment: Well, not quite *that* particular -- 334.40(B) permits the use of NM splice kits for exposed cables, and repair work in concealed cables (just not new installations of concealed cabling)

Comment: Well since the notches are already there i guess ill add 6ft 2x4 or 2x6 supports across the sides of truss where the notches exists.

Comment: @Dean *cringe*  I would go after the seller's title insurance company for the costs, then. That should have been disclosed or justified (e.g. they are 2x6 and only 2x4 is required).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica You’re not suggesting you cut stripes and add them to the attic until they know the structural capabilities of the existing structure, are you?

Answer (score 1):

Some people are lucky. I suspect you’re one of those...

You say it’s a 2x6 bottom chord of truss that extends across your house. If so, the member is in tension and a small notch will not matter, provided: 1) the span is not greater than 50’ or 40’ in a heavy snow zone, AND 2) you do not overload the new space.

1) Bottom chords of trusses are in tension only. So, notching the member does not affect the “bending moment” because it’s not in bending. A 2x6 bottom chord is extremely large. Most are 2x4’s. Taking a notch out of the 2x6 will not cause a failure unless the truss is over stressed.

The bottom chord could be over stressed if there is an extra long span, extra large snow load, or an extra large floor load from above, or a superimposed load from the roof.

2) Ceiling or attic spaces are designed for about 10 lbs. per square foot. When you add plywood to the top of the 2x6’s and start storing things on top, you’ve changed the space from attic to living space. Living spaces are suppose to be designed for 40 lbs. per square foot. So, you can do what you want, just don’t overload any one area.  (Store Christmas decorations not stacks of books.)

Btw, a picture of your attic would help confirm my answer.

Comment: On the other hand, there are two things I would not do: a) waste additional capacity, since the point of this exercise is to store stuff here, which will increase loading on the truss.  Nor b) go out and have an engineer review it, because that costs money.  I also would not trust the homeowner to *know* not to store books there.  I'd store books there LOL...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I cant think of anything heavier than stacks of books, unless they owned a machine shop.

Comment: So lee. Am i better off just leaving it as is or would adding 2x6 or 2x6 on one or both sides of the chords across notched area ( below the notch since i am using it to recess the wires) help support the area or would that cause more weakness my adding nail or screw holes in the bottom chords?

Comment: @Dean It depends. Hammering a zillion nails into the side of a chord or nailing too close to a joint can significantly weaken the overall system. (That’s why they usually use nail guns or screws.) First, I’d like to confirm the structural system is indeed a truss system and what type. A few pics will confirm that. Then, going to your local truss manufacturer and asking a few key questions could confirm my answer. (I’ll give you a list of questions.) They have software they can run that will give you the answer in about 2 minutes.

Comment: Well I was wrong, the notches are 1" deep x 3 1/2" long at deepest/longest areas. Man, what a wakeup call. I have not been able to sleep and feel sick to my stomach. I have also been using this area for a lot of storage and racks hanging from underneath in the garage. I have since removed all heavier item. I had no idea there was a limit of 10 lbs per sq ft on these trusses. per sq ft on these trusses.

Comment: I have contacted a local truss building company to advise me if I need to do any reinforces or they are still ok. I am hoping for the lather of the two, I will have to deal with consequences because of my dump ass move. By the way, a couple of question you have asked. The chord is 38ft long from front to back. The notches are 9ft from chord joint on one side and 4ft from the other side. I don't see how to add pictures. I hope I get some good new

Comment: @Dean Remember, the 10 lbs. per square foot is an average. So, if you have 30 lbs. in one area, an area of 3 square feet around it with no load will “average” out. Btw, are you sure they are manufactured roof trusses? Do they have metal plates where all the chords meet?

Comment: Yes they are manufactured trusses and have metal plates at all joints. With cross members coming of center to both sides and then two others going further out from there. How do you add pictures?

Comment: @lee. So based on what you know you still think there is not an issue?

Comment: @Dean Yes, I think you are ok. The length of the notch is not important...it’s the depth. You’ve basically turned the 2x6 into a 2x5. I doubt the member is stressed to its max. In residential design we have a safety factor of about 50% ...for situations just like this. We know home owners are likely to do anything. Also, wood members are designed to fail in “tension” first, rather than compression. That is to say, you’ll see cracks near those trusses before they completely collapse. The cracks will start when the trusses reach their maximum load resistance...probably when it snows.

Comment: @Lee Thank you for the information. Would you recommend i do a repair on these chords to be safe, if so what would you recommend? 
I am still trying to get the truss company to provide me some info and they are slow about it. I am considering hiring a structural engineer. Are you an engineer?

Comment: @lee by the way, what are the questions i should ask the truss company to determine if there is an issue?

Comment: @Dean  I don’t give out who I am, but I have years of structural training, design, etc.  I would just ask them to layout a truss for your span using local snow codes, seismic requirements, etc. AND have them lay it out using a 2x5 bottom chord. They’ll find that unusual and their program may not allow the use of 2x5’s. Then, I’d have them use 2x4’s and see if it’s over stressed, and if so by how much. If it is by...say 10%, then a 2x5 is satisfactory. (Area of 2x4 = 5.25 square inches and 10% is 0.525 sq. inches ...and the area of a 2x5 = 6.75 sq. inches. Therefore, a 2x5 would be acceptable.)

Comment: @lee ok, trusses company said their software does not do edge cuts, so referred my to engineer they work with. See what he can do. But the trusses company did run the program with the style of trusses i have (fink) my roofing type, using 2x6 chords (would not let then use a 2x4 on a 38ft span and i assume area conditions. Says the trusses is stressed 72%. What exactly does that mean for me? I still plan to get engineer buy off but curious. Dean

Comment: @Dean The trusses are designed for either “ultimate load” or “working stress load”. If the truss manufacturer says its stressed to 72% of “ultimate load” with a 2x6 chord member, then it’s now over stressed with the notches. However, if it’s 72% of the working stress load, then you’re probably ok with the notches. I’d check with the truss manufacturer for a clarification.

Comment: Lee, i emailed the guy at truss co. Waiting to hear back. But don't you think he would have been talking about working load?

Comment: @Dean Depends on the software. Hopefully he knows the difference.

Comment: @lee. Here is what the truss guy sent me regarding my trusses using 2x6. Does it mean they are not even stressed 50% with the loads he gives? 
Hi Dean,
With my design the bottom chord is at 0.42
This load is 25 psf snow + 8 psf top chord dead + 7 psf bottom chord dead.

Comment: @Dean  Like I said, “Some people are lucky...and you are one of them.” Yes, the bottom chord is not overstressed, even with the notches. However, the bottom chord is only designed for 7 psf Dead Load. The ceiling material weighs about 2 psf, the 2x4’s weigh about 0.5 psf and insulation could weigh between 1 psf to 4 psf depending on the type and thickness. (You can google the type and thickness of insulation to verify.) So, I would not add much, if any, additional load. Remember, their calculations are for a 2x6 bottom chord and you have something less. You are lucky.

Comment: Thank you lee. I appreciate all your input. This does help me not stress as much for sure. I am still going to get engineering buy off and i am hoping he will bless it as is. 
I will certainly limit my storage especially over the 5 trusses that have the notches. 
With the stress on bottom chord so low, taking in consideration these 5 trusses are basically 2x5, how much percent of stress would that add?

Comment: @Dean It’s strictly based on area. You can carefully measure the net area of what remains at each truss and divide it by 8.25 square inches (1.5” x 5.5”). It should be around 80% depending on how deep you made the cuts.

Comment: So 80% of board is left. So it adds 20% less stress or strength? That would put them at 62% stress on those trusses?

Comment: @Dean Yes, at approximately 50% stressed, adding about 20% stress means the chords are at about 60% stressed now.

Comment: Btw, I don’t know if I should tell you, but there is a little known structural clause in the code that allows the designer to use up to 30% higher stress values based on the “duration of snow load”. That is to say, they must design for 25 psf, but if you live where the snow only lasts for less than a week, they can increase the stress values in the wood, which is typically done where I live. (I forget the increase for locations where the snow lasts less than a month, but your engineer will know. Remind him of “short duration loading”.)

Comment: So they over design to allow for additional weight from snow? And you are saying its actually not stressed to what they say ? Am i following you? Btw, i still will watch my storage loads regardless. 
Im sorry am i understanding what you are saying?

Comment: My trusses where over designed with 2x6 because the design using my span will not work with 2x4 and because the next available size was 2x6 it created so over design by default. And your telling me i actually have even more then what he told me because of the code clause.

Comment: I promise to to over load things. But up until now i have been even with the notches. Not understanding there was a low limit on dead load for lower chords. What a lessen i have been getting.

Comment: @Dean Residential design is over sized for most items. They’re afraid the public will do something silly. You’re almost a structural engineer now. You just need a couple of books that show allowable loads for various joists and you could start your own consulting firm.

Comment: @ lee. Based on what you know. Do you think i should pay a structural engineer to tell me if my trusses are compromised and notches will affect there design strength and a repair if needed, Or just disclose it whrn i sell the house and provide the information the truss company gave me? So far i have almost 1000.00 quote from one engineer. Thanks for your input

Comment: @Lee. The engineer the truss co sent me too says he will make me repair it regardless of what the numbers say. Which i wonder if that does more harm, more holes, extra weight, etc. His fee is 350.00 which is more reasonable. Thoughts?

Comment: Your original post indicated you were adding plywood for a storage. If you forget about the storage, I don’t think repairing the bottom chord is necessary. However, I’d double check the exact depth of each cut. If there’s one cut that is excessively deeper than the 1” we’ve been discussing, then I’d repair that truss.

Comment: Ok i am going to do the repair. The notches could be 1/8 +/- more on one or two but thats it. I will use it for some storage, but nothing heavy, spread it out and limit the amount. I just was wondering if adding the extra weight to trusses if not really needed would be better or worst then just leaving it alone

Comment: The truss repair adds minimal weight. Far more damage can be done to the bottom chord by hammering nails into a sistered joist. I’d use self-tapping screws and be careful 1) not to place the screws too close together to split the bottom chord or the sistered joist, 2) not to damage the metal plate that joins the webs to the bottom plate, 3) not to hit the bottom chord damaging the fasteners from the ceiling material into the bottom chords.

Comment: He kind of gave me a verbal on repair. He said use 2x6 HF #1 scab, .138 x 3” wood screws and 1 1/2 edge margin, stager screws 4 to 6 in spacing. But he did say to use a 8ft 2x6 centered over notched area Which would put it right over metal plate and to edge of joint on the one side. So he is going to have to shorten the board or allow 3 ft on one side and 5 ft on other. I plan to talk to him about it when i get him all the info. I am going to hire him (350) so I can get engineering seal on buyoff

Comment: It all sounds about right to me. Is he a structural engineer or a civil engineer? (His stamp will say...) make sure he stamps his written recommendation.

Comment: Oh, that’s stamp and seal it...sign over the stamp.

Comment: He is a structural engineer and yes it will have his seal stamped on paperwork

Comment: @Lee. Thanks again Lee. I Know it's of my own doing but I am totally stressed over this whole issue. Now you have me worried about splitting the existing trusses. Please tell me I have nothing to worry about and just do the repair per engineering and all will be good. And then tell me I am a dumb ass for doing it in the first place.

Comment: If you don’t have a lot of construction experience, I’d do a quick mock-up. That is to say, buy 2 pieces of “kiln-dry” lumber and try screwing them together at about 4” on center staggered. Staggered means placing one screw about 2” from one edge and the next screw about 2” from the opposite side. This will put the screws in different grain patterns. (Screws 8” on center in same grain pattern should be fine.) You’ll be able to see what happens to the lumber and see if it tends to split. (Btw, the reason you want “kiln-dry” lumber is because

Comment: Is because that is probably what your chord is now that it has been in your attic for awhile. Also, green lumber is more forgiving and probably won’t split as easy.). Also, make sure you do not do this work with 2’ of snow on the roof. Also, borrow a friends screw gun that can easily drive the screws...   You’ll be fine. You’d be surprised how often trusses need to be repaired.

Comment: @Lee. I actually am mechanically incline and can built things. Its not that i can’t do it. It just irritates me that i did a dump ass move. I normally read up on something before doing it. Not sure what i was thinking when i did this 8 yes ago. Ya i was thinking the same thing, not doing it was snow on roof and i have Ryob screw gun.

Comment: Which also brings me to question why the engineer would force a repair if the truss strength is not structurally compromised when there is a chance of splitting the truss. Or is the chance of spitting the wood only if you don't stagger the screws?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any details of the structure, it's safer to add 1" thick strips (with gaps for the wires) to raise the floor slightly than to notch the (lower truss member or joist) since that may already be marginal at carrying the load.

You should use protective steel plates over the wire gaps to resist anyone nailing into them later on.

Comment: They are 2 x 6 ceiling joists or lower trusts that run across walls from front to back of house. Its actual only about 1/2 in botch. Can that really affect the strengh?